# How to order list in custom Item class with linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I have two classes

```
class Variant
{
    bool isOrdered;
}
class Item
{
    List<Variant> Variants;
}
```

Then I get `IQueryable<Item>` from my data source. I wand to order List of variants. 
e.g If execute query `IQueryable<Item>` we get:
 
 
{Item: Variants:{true,false,true}, Item: Variants:{false, false, true}, Item: Variants:{true,false,true,false}}
 
 and after ordering I need to get
 {Item: Variants:{true,true, false}, Item: Variants:{true,true,false}, Item: Variants:{true,true,false,false}}
 
I'm trying something like

```
var query =
        from item in source
        from variants in item.Variants
        orderby variants.isOrdered
        select item;
```

but instead of ordering variants this query order items and I have no idea how to order variants.

Comment: Are you looking to order the variants only or the items too? If items too, what's the ordering criteria?

Comment: only variants. (Comments must be at least 15 characters in length.)

Comment: And you are interested on selecting the variants only, right? Or do you need the items too?

Comment: I need to select items too and more In item can be more than one field).

Comment: That changes the context. Do you need the items ordered in a particular way? Are you able to change or add to the source code of `Variant`?

Comment: I don't need to change order of items but only order for variants in each item. Yes source code of variant's can change over time, and in my particular way item's has 30+ fields.

Comment: I updated my answer. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you are interested on is merely the variants, you could try:

```
var selections = source.Select(i => i.Variants.OrderByDescending(v => v.isOrdered));
```

`selections` will then be an `IEnumerable<IOrderedEnumerable<Variant>>` with three enumerations of variants (based on your sample data), ordered in this manner:

> True,True,False
>
> True,False,False
>
> True,True,False,False

**UPDATE:**

OP has updated the question to require the item as well, so...

There are a few ways to go about this. The least OOP-based, least intrusive one would be to grab the item as well as the sorted variant list into an anonymous type:

```
var selections = source.Select(i => new 
{ 
    Item = i, 
    SortedVariants = i.Variants.OrderByDescending(v => v.isOrdered)
});
```

In this case, `selections` will be an `IEnumerable<'a>` where `'a` is the anonymous type. The type will have two properties: the item that the variants belong to as well as a property called `SortedVariants`.

Then there is the simplest, non-reusable way. Every time you access the variants, sort them:

```
foreach (var item in source)
{
    var variants = item.Variants.OrderByDescending(v => v.isOrdered);          
    //Do something with the variants
}
```

A more reusable way is to add another property (or method) to the `Variant` class that returns the variant list in the desired order:

```
public class Item
{   
    public List<Variant> Variants;

    public IOrderedEnumerable<Variant> OrderedVariants
    {
        get { return Variants.OrderByDescending(v => v.isOrdered); }
    }

    //OR

    public IOrderedEnumerable<Variant> GetOrderedVariants()
    {
        return Variants.OrderByDescending(v => v.isOrdered);
    }
}
```

You can then use that property or method instead.

Lastly, if you have the flexibility to change the current design, you can always hide the list behind an interface and implement a method to add:

```
public class Item
{   
    private List<Variant> _variants = new List<Variant>();
    public IEnumerable<Variant> Variants
    {
        get { return _variants.OrderByDescending(v => v.isOrdered); }            
    }

    public void AddVariant(Variant variant)
    {
        _variants.Add(variant);
    }
}
```

This would my personal favorite since it provides the variants, satisfies the requirement and hides the details of the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

if you only want to sort Variant do this :

```
var SortedVariantItems= Items.Select(x =>new Item {Variants= x.Variants.OrderByDescending(c => c.isOrdered).ToList()})
```

and if you want In addition to Variant, Items also be sorted(by Variant) do this:

```
var SortedItems= Items.Select(x =>new Item {Variants= x.Variants.OrderByDescending(c => c.isOrdered).ToList()}).OrderByDescending(x=>x.Variants.Count(c=>c.isOrdered));
```

Comment: Creating new items for the sake of sorting inner properties does not seem like a good idea to me.

Comment: according to question " `... and after ordering I need to get
{Item: Variants:{true,true, false}, Item: Variants:{true,true,false}, Item: Variants:{true,true,false,false}} ` " We also want Items. But you only return the variants. What if the item had other fields?

Comment: Yeap you solution is work, but in my project `Item` has over 30 fields and it change over time. Have you some idea how I can deal with it?

Comment: yes i have idea . if you don't want to create new item every time , you have to use IComparable interface .do you know how to use it?see this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/320727/how-to-use-the-icomparable-and-icomparer-interfaces-in-visual-c) .if you had any question i can help you . i Hope it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

I  would suggest something like the below.

```
var orderedItems = Items.OrderBy(item => item.Variants.Where(v => v.isOrdered).Count());
```

This orders the items by how many of it's variants are ordered. You could replace whatever you like in the where.